# Apache give HTTP 404 error for all request when use custom perl module

Tags: apache, perl-module, apache2.2

I have to create the go remote-import server for my project using by apache and I try to create perl module for handler the go get request from user.

The perl module (RemoteImport.pm) was show in below:

```
sub handler{
    my $r = shift;

    # check if request is from "go"
    return Apache2::Const::DECLINED if ($r->args() !~ /go\-get=1$/);

    // Code for provide necessary http body data for go get request and return OK.
}
```

Apache config:

```
PerlModule Gerrit::Go::RemoteImport
<Location />
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler Gerrit::Go::RemoteImport
</Location>
```

The go get request can be use normally but I found problem in another http request that have path begin with "/", the Apache does not continue to serve the request as it normally and give not-found page.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solution from my team as bellow:

```perl
sub go_remote_import_response {
    my $r = shift;

    # Code for provide necessary http body data for go get request and return OK.
}

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;

    # check if request is from "go"
    return Apache2::Const::OK if ($r->args() !~ /go\-get=1$/);

    # change the response handler to our handler if the request are from "go"
    $r->handler('perl-script');
    $r->set_handlers(PerlResponseHandler => \&go_remote_import_response);

    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}
```